# How to view processes in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse there used to be a window showing the processes that are running on a device:[image]

Is there a way to view such in Android Studio?

Where exactly do I look for my own created process to kill it?

Google doesn't help, suprisingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, almost half a year later, after having searched all over Android Studio at the time when I asked the question, I accidentally found the `Processes` tab right inside `Device Explorer`!

Usually `Device Explorer` is on the right side of Android Studio, but in case it isn't there, you can find it at `View → Tool Windows → Device Explorer`.

[image]

[image]